# Determine $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, recursion

Given  $a,b\in\mathbb R$ , defined  $(a_n)_n$ recursively  by setting

$a_1 = a$ ,$ a_2 = b$ ,$ a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2n}a_{n-1}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}a_n,\;\;n\geq 2 $

Determine  $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$

My attempt :  I know   that $a_n = a + (b-a) +.......+ (a_n - a_{n-1})$   after that  I'm not able to procede  further.

any hints/solution will be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: May I ask where you found that task? (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$ a_{n+1} - a_n =  - \frac{1}{2n}(a_n - a_{n-1}) $$

Thus $a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n)!!}(b-a)$

$$
a_n - a = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_{i+1}- a_{i}) = (a - b) \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i)!!}
$$

The summation certainly converges, but I don't know how to get the converged value

According to [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(-1)%5Ei%2F(2i)!!,%20%7Bi,1,Inf%7D%5D), (and thanks to @Minus One Twelfth hint)
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i)!!} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i!}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^i - 1 = e^{-1/2} - 1
$$

In summary, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\right) b + \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}a$

Comment: Why from this we'll get a convergence?

Comment: By the way, for the infinite sum, we can use [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799348/an-identity-for-the-product-of-even-numbers-double-factorial) that $\color{blue}{(2i)!! = 2^{i}i!}$ and then use the Taylor series for $e^{x}$.

Comment: Thanks @MinusOne-Twelfth, that solves the summation analytically

Comment: @MoonKnight Can we prove $a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n)!!}(b-a)$ by descending induction? That way I got  $\frac{1}{2n\cdot2(n-1)\cdot2(n-2)\cdot\ldots}$ when adding all the terms which is the pattern for the Taylor series.